# Remove Sub Totals from Power BI Version 2.11

Tags: powerbi, report, powerbi-desktop, subtotal

[image]

How to remove sub totals. I just want a grand total at the end but want to remove all columns sub total

I tried to remove subtotals see below image. but Power BI still showing sub totals.  nothing happened.

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: Switch on `Per row level`, then for each `Series` in the `Series` dropdown, toggle off `Show subtotal` except for `Full_Name`.